# Why is Jinja2 rendering title tag in the body of my template using flask?

Tags: python, flask, web-applications, jinja2

I'm been learning the Flask framework and am confused how Jinja/Flask is able to render a `<head>` element inside a `<body>` tag.  It does this on all my child templates and I believe that my code is exactly like my two tutorial videos tell me to.  I'm not sure why it does this and how my code is wrong; all of the other `{% block %}` tags work normally.

Here is my base template:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>
        {% block title %} ⚠!⚠!⚠!⚠!⚠ {% endblock %}
    </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles/noauth.css') }}" />
    <link rel="icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles/favicon.png') }}" type="image/png" />
</head>
<body>
    
<div class="container">
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my child template (one example):

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %} !⚠ Access Denied! ⚠! {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="">
    <center>
        <h1>Yo, go <a href="{{ url_for('index') }}"><big>BACK</big></a> and put the password in!</h1>
    </center>
</div>
<br/>
{% endblock %}
```

Here is what it's doing on all child templates that inheret `base.html`:

[Title In Body Flask/Jinja2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O173O.png)

I'm wondering if it's possible that sublime text has ruined my code. A couple of comments I saw online mentioned it, but it was still very illogical even though I did have some text editor problems. I'm looked through all of my code and tried everything I could think of, but I'm still not sure how to fix this error.

Comment: Do you have something like `* { display: block; }` in your css?

Comment: @DanielB I do yes, what would this interfere with a `<title>` tag in `<body>` ??!  I'll remove that now and see.

Comment: `*` will match the `head` and `title` tags, setting them `display: block`, which makes them visible in the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@danielb helped me in the comments figure out that having `* {display: block;}` in my CSS was causing this very strange error.  Thanks to them and this is twice today that I had bizarre errors because of a `display:`  setting.

The reason for this is because `*` will set `display: block;` to `<head><title>` elements but use in the document because of the `display: block;`.  TIL that CSS applies styles to `<head>` items also.